# how to check from linux sh torrent file has completelly downloaded

Tags: bittorrent, flag

Ad far as I researched there is no android app that may be able to download a file directly into a shared drive.
Therefore I am developing a small routine in termux (linux) that cron checks all possible folder where files may be downloaded.
I have created on android a mirror paths from the shared drive so when I select from the app UI (LibreTorrent, excellent in many other ways) where the downloaded files are to be stored in android, the routine moves the file in the same exact directory in the shared drive without any further ado.
For this to work it is essential that my sh routine checks whether the download of each file is completed. File created by the torrent remains, though, the same from its creation to completion (I was expecting to see .part or the likes while file is downloading so to wait until it disappears. No cigar). However, since the downloaded status is shown in the app, the info must be available somewhere. What do you think i should check ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you. Question is: how do I check a downloading torrent file status (downloading ,downloaded) . When my linux routine is able to detect the status then it may proceed or wait for download completion to move the downloaded file. E.g. some of win downloader add a .part ext to the dowloading file and remove when done: easy to detect downloading stat. No Android I try has similar mechanism yet the needed info is shown in the UI: there must be a way my routine get hold of it!